# How to make variable of void global?

Tags: variables, void

I am a beginner programer and I want to ask how can I change integer variable pontok in void to public? So when it changes value in void, the variable could be reachable by the whole program. Please help me! Thank you!

```
int pontok;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String cmd = evt.getActionCommand();
        if (cmd == "Accept"){
            acceptAnswer();
        }
        else if (cmd == "Retry"){
            tryAgain();
        }
        else if (cmd == "Next"){
            nextTeam();
        }
        else if (cmd == "Return"){
            backToMenu();
        }
        else if (cmd == "Finish"){
            finishGame();
        }
    }


    public void acceptAnswer(){
        String team = nev.getText();
        team = team.toLowerCase();
        nev.setEditable(false);
            if (csapat[i].equals(team)){
            next.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else{retry.setEnabled(true);
            accept.setEnabled(false);
        }
        }
    public void tryAgain(){
        nev.setEditable(true);
        retry.setEnabled(false);
        accept.setEnabled(true);
        nev.setText(null);
        pontok = pontok - 10;
        points.setText("Your points:"+ pontok );

    }
    public void nextTeam(){
        nev.setEditable(true);
        next.setEnabled(false); 
        nev.setText(null);
        pontok = pontok + 100;
        points.setText("Your points:"+ pontok );
        fel.setText("Kerem a kepen lathato csapat nevet!");
        i++;
        image = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource(csapatok[i]));
        label.setIcon(image);
```

Comment: In what language are you working ? I _think_ I understand what you want to do and, if my understanding is correct then you don't understand what 'void' means in C/C++.  Void is not a wildcard as you want to use it, so you cannot change potnok to void and hope that it will suddenly not be matched by actionPerformed. The best you can do is set the integer to a variable that does not appear in the case.

Comment: I am using Java and I want to use the changed value of pontok in another program, but the actionListener changes the value, so I want to be able to somehow reach the pontok after Action Listener.